# UIView to UIImage conversion not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I am trying to get a screenshot of a UIView which is rotated. This is my code

```
-(void)rotateImage:(int)radian
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

// The transform matrix
CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseImageView.transform, M_PI/2 * radian);
self.baseImageView.transform = transform;
}

-(NSData *)getData
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO,0.0);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
}
```

Screenshot is created successfully,  but after that all the viewcontrollers i present is presented from top left and views bounce & misbehave. However if i create screen shot without rotating the image everything is fine. I am stuck with it any help is appreciated.

Note : i already tried modifying UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions parameters . My project does not use ARC.

Comment: Do you ever call `[UIView commitAnimations];`?

Comment: Unrelated but why aren't you using ARC? That's just silly.

Comment: And why are you using `beginAnimations`? It's like you are living in iOS 3.

Comment: Dumb me ! i forgot to add [UIView commitAnimations]; and that was the problem.

Comment: @maddy The project is old and the project owners are comfortable with MRC.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the animation was not handled properly.I ended up doing this to solve the problem.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn  animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseImageView.transform, M_PI/2 * radian);
    self.baseImageView.transform = transform;
} completion:nil];
```